# how to append new lines to html output file

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a code which creates few lists(recording files) per userid and then write it to a html file

```
if get_excel == 'yes':
    download_file = {'user_id' : userid_c, 'Recording_name' : chaptername, 'Download_link' : all_downloadlinks, 'Recording_date_time' : created, 'Duration_in_minutes' : duration_array}
    df = pd.DataFrame(download_file)
    df["Download_link"] = df["Download_link"].apply(lambda x: "<a href='{0}'>click here</a>".format(x))
    df.to_html('Recordings.html', render_links=True,escape=False,)

 s += 1
```

and then it loops back to other userid's in the list. when the second users lists are written to the html file, it overides the existing html file rather than appending the new values to the existing one.

How i can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file once outside the loop, then write to that file with `to_html()`.

```
with open('Recordings.html', 'w') as htmlfile:
    # other code ...
    if get_excel == 'yes':
        download_file = {'user_id' : userid_c, 'Recording_name' : chaptername, 'Download_link' : all_downloadlinks, 'Recording_date_time' : created, 'Duration_in_minutes' : duration_array}
        df = pd.DataFrame(download_file)
        df["Download_link"] = df["Download_link"].apply(lambda x: "<a href='{0}'>click here</a>".format(x))
        df.to_html(htmlfile, render_links=True,escape=False,)
    
    s += 1 
    # more code ...
```

Comment: Followed your suggestion but the output file still show only the data of last looped userid
output: https://ibb.co/7j4J7bB

Comment: <a href="https://ibb.co/7j4J7bB"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ckLczxR/2022-06-10-08-04-40.png" alt="2022-06-10-08-04-40" border="0"></a>

Comment: You'll have to post more code in the question, I don't have enough context to see why it's not working. Did you make sure the `with` line is OUTSIDE the loop?

Comment: These images don't help me tell what's wrong in your code.

Comment: Yes i added it outside the loop. Here is the code https://textdoc.co/vSFmV3uLTUnHh5if

Comment: I don't see a loop inside the `with`.

Comment: The only loop I see is `while s < length:` and this code isn't around it.

Comment: Yes `while s < length` is the main loop to change the userid after it completes printing the data to the html file. There is no loop inside the `with`.
So shall i add the `with` code inside the the main loop?

Comment: i moved inside the `while s < length` loop but it does the same thing. https://i.postimg.cc/CLhn5RLz/2022-06-10-08-32-36.png

Comment: You still don't have `with` *around* the loop. I think you just don't understand the point I'm making. You open the file once at the beginning. Then you loop, adding to the file each time through the loop. Then you close the file (which is done automatically by leaving the `with` block).

Comment: Sorry it took some time for me to understand. Now i moved the `with` block around the loop and it worked. Thank you for your patience.